# Double poles in propagators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, analyticity

I'm curious as to how to interpret double poles in the propagator. In general, the poles of a propagator tell us the mass.

1. For example, for a free, massive scalar
   $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\phi(\Box-m^2)\phi,$$
   with equations of motion
   $$(\Box-m^2)\phi=0,$$
   the propagator goes like
   $$G(k)\sim \frac{1}{k^2+m^2},$$
   and has a pole at the mass, $k^2=-m^2$.
2. However, if one considers a higher-derivative theory, say
   $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\phi(\Box-m^2)^2\phi,$$
   with equations of motion
   $$(\Box-m^2)^2\phi=0,$$
   the propagator goes like
   $$\tilde{G}(k)\sim \frac{1}{(k^2+m^2)^2}.$$
   This is a *double* pole at $k^2=-m^2$, and I was wondering what the interpretation of this is. Naively, one might say that the mass is still $m$; however, it is a double pole (and hence has zero residue), and so it feels like this interpretation should fail, but is there something that saves this viewpoint? Alternatively, a strong stance would be to claim that the theory breaks down, but if that is the case, then why is there a breakdown?

Comment: In what sense is this an interaction term? The Lagrangian is quadratic in the fields, and the path integral is just a Gaussian, so I'm not quite sure I understand how this isn't a free (higher-derivative) field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If we start with OP's higher-derivative Lagrangian
   $$ {\cal L} ~=~ \frac{1}{2}[(\Box-m^2)\phi]^2, \tag{A} $$
   one idea is to try to lower the number of derivatives by introducing more fields, e.g.
   $$ {\cal L}_1 ~=~ \chi (\Box-m^2)\phi - \frac{1}{2}\chi^2. \tag{B} $$
   If we integrate out the $\chi$ field,
   $$ {\cal L}_1\quad\stackrel{\chi}{\longrightarrow}\quad{\cal L} \tag{C}$$
   we return to OP's higher-derivative theory.
2. However, when we diagonalize the kinetic terms
   $$ {\cal L}_1 ~\stackrel{(B)+(E)}{=}~ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\pm}\pm\phi_{\pm} (\Box-m^2)\phi_{\pm} - \frac{1}{4}(\phi_+-\phi_-)^2, \tag{D} $$
   with
   $$\phi_{\pm} ~=~\frac{\phi\pm\chi}{\sqrt{2}},\tag{E}$$
   it becomes apparent that the
   $\phi_-$ field has the wrong sign in front of its kinetic term, i.e. it is a [bad ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_(physics)). This is typical for higher-derivative theories, cf. the [Ostrogradsky instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability).